# array_agg with distinct works in postgres 9.4 but not in postgres 9.6

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.6, array-agg

I have a query that use array_agg with distinct as an argument and is not accepted on postgres 9.6.

I created this sample to illustrate the issue:

```
create table numbers (id integer primary key, name varchar(10));
insert into numbers values(1,'one');
insert into numbers values(2,'two');
```

postgres 9.4

```
select array_agg(distinct(id)) from numbers;
 array_agg 
-----------
 {1,2}
```

postgres 9.6

```
ERROR:  function array_agg(integer) is not unique
LINE 1: select array_agg(distinct(id)) from numbers;
               ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. 
You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

What do I need to change in order to get this result on postgres 9.6?

Thanks.

This is what I get checking the functions:

```
nspname | proname | proargtypes 
------------+-----------+--------------------- 
pg_catalog | array_agg | [0:0]={anyarray} 
public | array_agg | [0:0]={anyelement} 
pg_catalog | array_agg | [0:0]={anynonarray
```

Now, I found the issue thanks to the comment by [pozs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1499698/pozs).  I remove the public definition of the aggregated function and it worked.

The issue was just on the database that I was working on, as I found some people saying that the sample worked for them I created a new database an run the example.  And then the only change there was the aggregate function definitions.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is **not**  a function. `distinct id` is the same as `distinct  (id)`

Comment: Your example works for me with 9.6.2: See here: https://i.imgur.com/PgaAkRD.png

Comment: thanks for your response, Ok, this is what I'm using exactly:

PostgreSQL 9.6.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) 5.3.1 20160413, 64-bit

Comment: It works on a Linux based installation for me as well: https://i.imgur.com/C7Td0OV.png

Comment: Maybe a UDF interferes? You can check that by listing all `array_agg` named function of yours, [f.ex. with this](http://rextester.com/MLHSEL68822).

Comment: This is what I get checking the functions:

  nspname   |  proname  |     proargtypes     
------------+-----------+---------------------
pg_catalog | array_agg | [0:0]={anyarray}
public     | array_agg | [0:0]={anyelement}
pg_catalog | array_agg | [0:0]={anynonarray}

Comment: @Browser_80 update the question with that.

Answer (score 7):

Now, I found the issue thanks to the comment by pozs. I remove the public definition of the aggregated function and it worked.

The issue was just on the database that I was working on, as I found some people saying that the sample worked for them I created a new database an run the example. And then the only change there was the aggregate function definitions.

So I drop the function public | array_agg | [0:0]={anyelement}  and it worked.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.
Can you explain what this function does? 
Also - how do you drop this function?

Answer (score 0):

It works exactly like that as demonstrated by this [dbfiddle on PostgreSQL 9.6.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, 64-bit](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=21eb333639fe641bd40e6c06937f2581).

[image]